# array to table with key name as vertical header

Tags: php

I have an array $a that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2015-10-11
            [Time] => 18:45:00
            [Protocol] => TLSv1.0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2015-10-11
            [Time] => 23:43:24
            [Protocol] => TLSv1.2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2015-10-11
            [Time] => 23:45:18
            [Protocol] => TLSv1.1
        )

)
```

I would like to manipulate the output into a vertical table to look like this:

```
Date      2015-10-11  2015-10-11  2015-10-11
Time      18:45:00    23:43:24    23:45:18
Protocol  TLSv1.0     TLSv1.2     TLSv1.1
```

Comment: DO you want a HTML table structure or console?

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump your to-do lists. Show what you've attempted so far, and we'll (maybe) try help fix it. But right now this is just "do my job for me".

Comment: yeah, basic html table will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
    // $arr is your array.
    $final = array();
    foreach ($arr as $chunk) {
        $final['Date'][] = $chunk['Date'];
        $final['Time'][] = $chunk['Time'];
        $final['Protocol'][] = $chunk['Protocol'];
    }
    ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($final as $k => $chunk) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $k ?></td>
                <?php foreach ($chunk as $row) { ?>
                    <td><?= $row ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: this works as expected! thank you